# Limit scope of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
var tr0HTML = $('<tr id="exp_line1"></tr>').appendTo(tbody);
```

What could the best possible way to use .css or any other jQuery to style this element based on the condition?

All I could see is that the change has been implemented to whole page not for the particular scenario!

Update: I want to style borders to the table which has 3 different types of rows. Rows are being displayed if the data is provided.

Comment: What style do you wanna apply based on what condition?

Comment: "based on the condition" -> what condition? Please elaborate, explain what you have and what you need.

Comment: I want to style borders to the table which has 3 different types of rows. Rows are being displayed if the data is provided.

Comment: "3 different types of rows"...what are the types? What's the difference between them? If you want to style them differently then CSS will need a way to tell them apart. Using CSS classes would make sense. Then you can give each class a different style. What have you tried or researched? This kind of thing is not hard to find out online, really. P.S. This has nothing directly to do with jQuery as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your question... Something as simple as this should work:

```css
tr.type-1 td{
  border: 2px solid hotpink;
}
tr.type-2 td{
  border: 2px solid purple;
}
tr.type-3 td{
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="type-1">
      <td>Type 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="type-2">
      <td>Type 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="type-3">
      <td>Type 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Your jQuery code would look like this: `$('<tr id="exp_line1" class='type-1'></tr>').appendTo(tbody)`